# Switch Authentication Handler in Authentication Manager

Tags: authentication, spring-security, jasperserver

I know there are hell lot of docs about Spring Security. However, I am unable to find answer to my problem.

As I understand, below configuration will make authentication manager to traverse through each authentication provider unless a match is found.

```
<bean id="authenticationManager" class="org.springframework.security.providers.ProviderManager">
    <property name="providers">
        <list>
            <ref local="ldapAuthenticationProvider"/>
            <ref bean="${bean.daoAuthenticationProvider}"/>
            <ref bean="anonymousAuthenticationProvider"/>

        </list>
    </property>
</bean>
```

However, I want to switch among available providers based on a request parameter, instead of trying all of them. I was wondering if its possible to switch using a filter or any other way?

Answer (score 0):

Subclass `ProviderManager` and override `getProviders()`.  Because `getProviders()` doesn't take any params you'll need to set a `ThreadLocal` somewhere in the filter chain with either the request or a flag that the request has the parameter you want.

Comment: I dropped the complete idea of doing this. So not sure if this answer would really work.